# How to check if a macro exists in an object file in C?

Tags: c, object-files

For example, I define a macro:

```
#ifdef VERSION
 //.... do something
#endif
```

How can I check if `VERSION` exist in my object file or not? I tried to disassemble it with `objdump`, but found no actual value of my macro `VERSION`. `VERSION` is defined in Makefile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try compiling with `-g3` option in `gcc`. It stores macro information too in the generated ELF file.

After this, if you've defined a macro `MACRO_NAME` just `grep` for it in the output executable or your object file. For example,

```
$ grep MACRO_NAME a.out # any object file will do instead of a.out
Binary file a.out matches
```

Or you can even try,

```
$ strings -a -n 1 a.out | grep MACRO_NAME

 -a Do not scan only the initialized and loaded sections of object files; 
    scan the whole files.

 -n min-len Print sequences of characters that are at least min-len characters long,
    instead of the default 4.
```

Comment: +1 for `-g3` ... - to then find the macro in the binary I'd prefer `strings <binary> | grep <macro>`.

Comment: @alk. I tried the strings version but the `MACRO_NAME` is so embedded into the object file that `strings` is not treating it as a string and grep fails.

Comment: Mea culpa, I just tested this and it seems you are right. Need to investigate on this one ... *out digging*

Comment: Ok, got it ... - use: `strings -a <binary> | grep <macro>` and it works. See `man strings` for what's going on.

Comment: @ouah somehow my drowsy mind is not able to spot the typo. Help :)

Comment: Ahh, idiot me! I switched to windows when I did the edit. So din verify. Thanks @ouah :)

Comment: @ouah Aaargh... Take this gun! Shoot my hellish brain. Edited!

Comment: Just for the record, there's also `dwarfdump`, it dumps DWARF debug information. You're most likely interested in `.debug_macro` sections. You can filter the others out like so, `dwarfdump path/to/binary | sed -En ':l1 /^\.debug_macro/ { $ { p; q }; h; :l2 n; $ { /^\./ { /^\.debug_macro/ { H } }; /^\./ ! H; x; p; q }; /^\./ ! { H; b l2 }; x; p; x; b l1 }'`. Not that it's not usable without `sed`, I just felt like doing some `brainfuck`'ing :) More on the script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52239152/52499).

Answer (score 0):

The following command displays contents of `.debug_macro` DWARF section:

```
$ readelf --debug-dump=macro path/to/binary
```

or

```
$ objdump --dwarf=macro path/to/binary
```

You can also use `dwarfdump path/to/binary`, but it's [not easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102851/how-to-check-if-a-macro-exists-in-an-object-file-in-c#comment91426929_10102889) to leave only `.debug_macro` section in the output.